# docker suprisingly persistent although it should not be

Tags: docker, docker-compose, persistence

I have a docker image running for powering a wordpress site. As far as I know, Docker images are not persistent. so any change i make will be discarded once i stop the image.

however, i entered the image like "docker exec -it [IMG] bash", ran "$ apt update" and did some "$ apt install [STUFF]" and even after i have stocked the image and restarted it, the installed packages are still present.

Shouldn't they dissapear? Isn't this the reason why these docker files always contain some "$ apt install [STUFF]"?

Comment: Stopping a container is like pausing it. Remove the stopped container (`docker rm <container-id>`), and it will be blank when started again.

Comment: By-the-by: [`docker exec` takes a container as parameter, not an image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

Comment: thanks. i always thought the images are like instantiated containers.

Comment: They are. But multiple containers can be started from the same image.

Comment: Containers are like instantiated images.